# Position Fixed CSS in Safari Mac OS only

Tags: css, safari

I'm currently having an issues with a fixed div header on a web-site that only occurs in Safari with Mac OS.

Essentially, there is a div with a css attribute of "position: fixed" but when scrolling in Safari Mac OS (only) some parts of the header stay fixed and some others don't. Funnily enough, when a javascript/jQuery plugin causes a refresh, the fixed header snaps back to where it should be.

The web-site is http://www.v2.ledcentral.com.au/.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The page looks the same to me in Safari 5.1 and Chrome 27.

Comment: I don't have a mac myself to I can't test it till tomorrow. But I've tested it on different machines and it's never worked. I wonder if you checked it after I applied the fix from Santz (below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have this kind of problems, I wrap the whole "element/s" with this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

This code snippet has been my Savior for long time since...

Luck, hope it helped

Comment: Santz, it worked a treat. I'll definitely keep that in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that position:fixed frequently causes some cross-browser issues.  I've found that a better approach is to make the header, then have a div under it which is itself scrollable (they don't scroll stuff under the header).

```
|---Browser Viewport----|
| |-------------------| ^
| | Title Bar Content | |
| | fixed position    | |
| | can change v-size | |
| |-------------------| |
|                       |
| Main Content          |
| which                 |
| runs                  |
| off                   |
| the                   |
| screen below          v
|-----------------------|
```

OR

```
|---Browser Viewport----|
|                       |
|  Title Bar Content    |
|  fixed position       |
|  but can change size  |
| |-------------------| |
| |Main Content       ^ |
| |which              | |
| |runs               | |
| |out of             | |
| |this div, below    v                  
| |-------------------| |
|-----------------------|
```

I hope that kind of explains what I'm talking about